# Easy exercise with boundary

Tags: general-topology

could I have a confirm or a suggestion about this little exercise?

> $\partial A=\emptyset$ if and only if $A$ is open and closed.

Sol.:

If $A$ is "clopen", then $Int(A)=A$ and $Cl(A)=A$, so $\partial A=A \setminus A=\emptyset $.

If $\partial A=\emptyset$, then $Cl(A) \setminus Int(A)=\emptyset$. So doesn't exist a $x \in Cl(A) \cap Int(A)$. Then $Cl(A)=Int(A)$, and this is possibile only if $A$ is clopen

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2389145/309917

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first part is O.K. Your second part is incomplete.

If $\partial A=\emptyset$ then $Cl(A) \setminus Int(A)=\emptyset$. It follows that

$Cl(A) \subseteq Int(A)$.

Since $Int(A) \subseteq A \subseteq Cl(A)$, we get

$$Int(A) = A = Cl(A).$$

Hence $A$ is clopen.

Comment: thanks so much! $Cl(A)⊆Int(A)$ is what I missed ;)

Answer (score 0):

I find easier this approach:

The boundary of $A$ is not empty $\iff$ there exists some $x\in\ Cl(A)\cap Cl(A^c)$ $\iff$ there exists some $x$ that has no neighbourhood contained in $A$ or $A^c$ $\iff$ $A$ is not open or $A^c$ is not open $\iff$ $A$ is not clopen.